# Crash error when updating from playstore PROD

Tags: android, forms, xamarin, updates

We got this issue today with XF3.0 and ONLY when updating from playstore for a new release in prod.

**Note :** This error is not happening when updating from Alpha Release or iOS, only prod Android.

If user uninstall and then reinstall the app, this error is removed and there is no crash.

We use Akavache and some custom renderers (map and controls for info ...)

Any idea on this ? Why it happens only when updating from playstore. What would cause this error/crash and why uninstalling and reinstalling the app would fix that. 
Could it be that the user updated the app while it was open ?

- What is doing playstore when an app is open and an update is being processed ?
- Does playstore closes it while installing the new version ?
- What happens when user clicks on "open" from playstore while app was opened and updated ?

UPDATE : after testing on multiple devices if we clear data from param/app/appname/clear data the app does not crash anymore. When updating an app isn't it supposed to clear data?

***Log error :***

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1386)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: 
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:1496)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: 
  at com.android.org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.keystore.bc.BcKeyStoreSpi.engineLoad (BcKeyStoreSpi.java:868)
  at java.security.KeyStore.load (KeyStore.java:1247)
  at mono.java.lang.RunnableImplementor.n_run (Native Method)
  at mono.java.lang.RunnableImplementor.run (RunnableImplementor.java:30)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:751)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:95)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:154)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6776)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so the prob was coming from Xamarin Auth 1.6.0.2 NugetPackage. Only solution is to downgrade at the moment ...

https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Auth/issues/297